# Why does my dictionary contain two entries with identical keys?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I created a dictionary as such:

```
Dictionary<byte[], MyClass> dic = new Dictionary<byte[], MyClass>();
```

the key is assumed to be a SHA1 hash of 20 bytes. So after having added two entries into that dictionary I checked with a debugger and both have the same byte array keys.

I thought dictionaries cannot do that?

PS: Here's how I add them:

```
string strText1 = "text";

SHA1 sha1_1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] bytesHash1 = sha1_1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText1));

string strText2 = "text";

SHA1 sha1_2 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] bytesHash2 = sha1_2.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText2));

dic.Add(bytesHash1, 1);
dic.Add(bytesHash2, 2);
```

Comment: What are the two entries, and how are they declared?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dictionaries *can't* do that (have duplicate keys).

However, your dictionary *doesn't* have duplicate keys, because the comparator will treat `byte[]` as a reference, effectively using the pointer rather than the content of the array.

If you want to use `byte[]` as the key, probably the easiest solution is to provide your own comparison class which checks the content rather than the reference value, something like:

```
public class BaComp: IEqualityComparer<byte[]> {
    public bool Equals (byte[] left, byte[] right) {
        // Handle case where one or both is null (equal only if both are null).

        if ((left == null) || (right == null))
            return (left == right);

        // Otherwise compare array sequences of two non-null array refs.

        return left.SequenceEqual (right);
    }

    public int GetHashCode (byte[] key) {
        // Complain bitterly if null reference.

        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ();

        // Otherwise just sum bytes in array (one option, there are others).

        int rc = 0;
        foreach (byte b in key)
            rc += b;
        return rc;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
Dictionary<byte[], MyClass> dic = new Dictionary<byte[], MyClass> (new BaComp());
```

Comment: I updated the question. So how do I add them "not as reference"?

Comment: You could convert them to a string or construct it with an appropriate `IEqualityComparer`.

Comment: @Јοеу: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I know what `IEqualityComparer` is. Can someone update the code and show me how it needs to be done?

Comment: Use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) to create the dictionary and pass an object with a subclass of [this class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx).

Comment: @c00000fd, I've added the code for a comparer which _should_ do what you want but I don't have the opportunity to test it at the moment so I may need to modify it later if it doesn't work.

Comment: Wow, it's not as simple as I thought. Thanks. I'd probably be better off if I converted sha1 into a string and used it as a key.

Comment: Why should it complain if it's a null reference? Should it not simply silently handle it?  It's not the container's job to make sure its contents are sensible.  Just return 0 for the hashcode.  Summing the bytes is also a truly awful way of generating it, especially since your byte array already literally contains a hash code anyway (that's what SHA1 is, a cryptographic hash function).  Just use the first 4 bytes: `return key[0] | key[1] << 8 | key[2] << 16 | key[3] << 24;`

Comment: @Wug, it's to stop people generating a hashcode for a null reference. The doco (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.gethashcode.aspx) specifically states that it throws that exception. If you want to go against MS' own doco, by all means, do so :-) And, as I stated, the byte summing is only one way to generate the hash code. I think you're seeing the trees instead of the forest here: the answers is to create your own comparator, _not_ to do that a certain way.

Comment: Ok.  I undownvoted because the documentation indicates that throwing the exception is legal (though nowhere does it say you have to).  The method of calculating the hashcode is still basically so bad that it subverts the entire point of calculating it anyway (notice that, as a dice rolling problem with 20d256, it will have a range of 0 to 5120 with a bias towards 2560 for the 20 byte SHA1 hashes, as well as being an O(n) operation in general as opposed to O(1)).  You lost most of the constant time efficiency of the dictionary with a hashcode like that.

Comment: Wug, you're right in the general case but, since the byte arrays are in this case fixed at twenty bytes, it's very much O(1). I'd choose a better hash function for more generalised data. But, I have to re-iterate, it's irrelevant to the question. If you think it would make a better answer, I'd be happy to incorporate a different hash, though there are usually limitations unless you tailor it specifically to likely data. I suspect it's not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to instantiate your dictionary using [this constructor (documentation):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx)

```
IEqualityComparer<byte[]> myComparator = GetMyComparatorSomehow();
Dictionary<byte[], MyClass> dic = new Dictionary<byte[], MyClass>(myComparator);
```

Your comparator should work as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx).